# Call java generics on nativescript to convert JSON to HashMap

Tags: java, json, generics, hashmap, nativescript

I'm building an Nativesctipt app for Android that uses Firebase as backend and I'm using the native Firebase Android library v2.4.0

I can insert objects in Firebase just fine using the following {N} Javascript syntax

```
var user = new java.util.HashMap();
user.put("name", viewModel.get("name"));
user.put("lastName", viewModel.get("lastName");

var address = new java.util.HashMap();
address.put("address", viewModel.get("address");
address.put("number", viewModel.get("number");
address.put("city", viewModel.get("city");

user.put("address", address);

ref = new Firebase("https://my-firebase-app-url/users");
refUser = ref.child(viewModel.get("username"));
refUser.setValue(user);
```

The problem with this is that I have to manually convert every javascript object into a java hashSet (and back) and I wanted to do it using a JSON to HashMap library so I have imported the java Jackson library into my {N} app.

According to [this site](http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-convert-java-map-to-from-json-jackson/) here's the way to convert a JSON to a HashMap in Java using Jackson:

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
String json = "{\"name\":\"mkyong\", \"age\":29}";

Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<String, Object>();

// convert JSON string to Map
map = mapper.readValue(json, new TypeReference<Map<String, String>>(){});
```

I'm looking for a way to translate that into a {N} Javascript code that will do it for me but I'm unable to use generics notation in {N} Javascript. Does anybody know how I could do it? I have tried some ways but all of them crashed the application. Here's an {N} Javascript snippet does **not** work:

```
var ObjectMapper = com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
var TypeReference = com.fasterxml.jackson.core.type.TypeReference;

var mapper = new ObjectMapper();
var map = mapper.readValue(JSON.stringify(user), new TypeReference());
refUser.setValue(map);
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Follow the discussion in {N} google [group](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/nativescript/X7DRSJxMNCU)